# Another automagic date field like created and updated in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

I already know that I can make fields called 'created' and 'updated' in a database table and that Cake will automatically insert the appropriate values.

However, what I would like to do is create a new field called 'followup' and have Cake automatically insert todays date plus 2 weeks whenever a new record was inserted. In other words, it's be just like the created date but 2 weeks in the future.

I know that I could do this in the controller manually but I was wondering if there was a way to do this at the model/behavior level so that it'd happen automagically regardless of which controller action was creating a new record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use the `beforeSave` callback in the model:

```
public function beforeSave(array $options) {
    if (empty($this->data[$this->alias]['id']) && !$this->id) {
        $this->data[$this->alias]['followup'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+2 weeks'));
    }
    return true;
}
```

This adds the `followup` date to any new record (without `id`) automatically.

Comment: Thanks @deceze -- that's exactly what I wanted to do. I had a feeling that it'd be something like that but my knowledge is still a bit limited in this area. Thanks for helping to expand my understanding of things!

Comment: you can also make this a behavior to use for more than one table and keep it dry and cakeish. ideas for that you can get from existing behaviors with simialr functionality - like "WhoDidIt" behavior etc.

Comment: Thanks @mark - actually, I was about to start integrating some auditing functionality into  my app so thanks for pointing out WhoDidIt -- that'll be a great help. :-)